# typescript : how to define type for object property?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have this **object** in my component

**one** of its **Property** has **type**

```
interface IProduct {
  artikelname: string
  artikelnummer: string
  barccode: string
}

form = {
  date: [],
  R2Os: [],
  type: 1,
  cats: null,
  selected_product: Array<IProduct>
}
```

but I think this way of **typing** is not **true**

and i have **error** ,

[image]

so, how Can I define **type** for **Object Property** ?

Comment: `form = { ... }` creates an object, your object literal must be a value, not a *type*. You'd specify the type to the left of the `=`, `form: { ... } = { ... }`, or in a separate `type` specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you do it by defining a type (like your `IProduct`) for the object as a whole, and assigning that type to the variable referring to the object (`form`) when you declare it. For instance:

```typescript
interface FormType {
    date: Array<something>;
    R20s: Array<something>;
    type: number;
    cats: null | something;
    selected_product: Array<IProduct>;
}
// ...
const form: FormType = {
//        ^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− giving type to object
    date: [],
    R2Os: [],
    type: 1,
    cats: null,
    selected_product: [],
    //                ^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− value
};
```

but you can also do it with an inline type assertion:

```typescript
const form = {
    date: [],
    R2Os: [],
    type: 1,
    cats: null,
    //                vv−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− value
    selected_product: [] as Array<IProduct>,
    //                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−− type assertion
};
```

The [TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html) is worth reading from beginning to end. It covers all of the basics in a very concise way.